# Могут ли сервлеты общаться друг с другом ?

Tags: gwt, servlet, java

Ситуация следующая:

Программа на Java использует GWT для запросов клиента к серверу. При этом разные запросы клиента обращаются (инициализируют при первом вызове, а затем используют) к разным сервлетам на одном сервере. Сервлеты тоже на Java (реализуют сервисы GWT).

Вопрос:

Возможно ли (и если, Да, то каким образом) организовать взаимодействие между сервлетами (в рамках сервера)?

Какое взаимодействие в принципе видится возможным в подобной ситуации ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вижу решение проблемы в небольшом рефакторинге кода:
  Как я понимаю, один сервлет должен вызвать некоторые методы в другом, то есть какие-то функции или переменные, или что-то еще, что использует более чем один сервлет. Мое предложение - вынести эти функции-поля-и т.д. в отдельный класс, объекты которого будут использовать разные сервлеты. Также объект этого класса можно поместить в сессию, если необходимо отслеживать некоторые изменения в разных сервлетах. Такой подход, по моему, более красивый.

Comment: Все ОК. Я попробовал. Статические поля являются общими для  **различных** сервлетов.

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно и по другому: сервлет А выполняет какую-то операцию, запихает в реквест данные. И форвардит запрос сервлету Б. итд...  Это позволяло запросу быть обработанным несколькими сервлетами с минимальными изменениями кода + каждый из них мог работать независимо (с точки зрения клиентской части).